# Laravel Reset Password Error, Attribute Email is not in user entity

Tags: laravel, authentication, model, controller, migration

so I'm having an error in Laravel reset password because I want to access email, not from user entity. I have deleted the email attribute in the user entity. So here are my models

User Models Has One To One Relationship with the team:

```
public function team()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Team::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

Team Models Has Many To Many Relationship with Participant:

```
public function participants()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Participant::class, 'team_id');
    }

public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
```

Participant Model:

```
public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_id');
    }
```

Here are the user migration, i already delete the email attribute:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('role');
            $table->string('username')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Here are the Team Migration

```
Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->string('name', 50);

            $table->string('status', 25);

            $table->timestamp('registration_date')->useCurrent();
            $table->string('invoice', 200)->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('nominal')->default('0');
            
            $table->foreignId('competition_id');
            $table->foreign('competition_id')->references('id')->on('competitions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            
            $table->foreignId('teacher_id');
            $table->foreign('teacher_id')->references('id')->on('teachers')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->char('login_token')->default('');
            
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And here is the Participant Migration, I want to send the forgot password's email on Participant email which has role == "leader"

```
 Schema::create('participants', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->string('nama', 50);
        $table->string('nis', 20)->nullable();
        $table->string('student_card', 100);
        $table->string('class', 10);

        $table->string('phone_number', 20);
        $table->string('email', 100);
        $table->string('address', 100)->nullable();

        $table->string('role');

        $table->foreignId('team_id');
        $table->foreign('team_id')->references('id')->on('teams')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

Please help me to solve this, thanks

Comment: In this case you probably need a custom User provider to fetch the email from another table: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm still confused about how to do it. Is there any concrete step where it explains the solution to my problem? sorry I'm still new to laravel.

Comment: Well, it is hard to understand if you've never worked with this part of the framework before but maybe you will understand it a bit more by watching this YouTube series about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKRLrJXNN4M&list=PLwAKR305CRO9S6KVHMJYqZpjPzGPWuQ7Q  Even if it's published 4 years ago, I think you will learn from it.